# Scroll to anchor after all async data and images are loaded

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scroll

I have one problem with my app. App aggregates some event list - each evant consist from several sections (description, speakers, location etc.). On main page I have event list (images, + some links). When I click on image - app is switching to event details (it's different route, controller and view). Now everything is ok. But I would like when user clicks link named "location" on event list main page - app should not only redirect to event details view but after that scroll down to section named location.

We used:

```
$document.scrollTo(document.getElementById('my_id'), 70);
```

Well - it worked, but some data in event details controller are loaded from firebase in async way - so id works, but after data is loaded (and images) - scroll position stays the same, but page content moves down (since data is loaded) and everything ends up with wrong scroll position.

So we wrapped this with:

```
$timeout(function() {
           $document.scrollTo(document.getElementById('my_id'), 70);
}, 1000);
```

And it helps - indeed scroll mechanism waits 1 sec and after all data is loaded and images are loaded - app scrolls down and scroll is at good position.

Beside fact that is in our opinion rather poor solution - it even sometimes fail - especially when there is slow network and data and images are loaded longer than 1sec. Of corse we can set timeout to 2sec - but problem remains the same.

Is there any chance to somehow bind (or broadcst and then bind) to event after all async data is loaded and also all images loaded and rendered? I tried every solution found (anchorScroll, jquery img load, broadcast event after all firebase element fetched and countinuus scroll after each event) in the internet but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to create an attribute directive that would
watch loaded attribute on scope and scroll content to the
element with this directive. You can switch `$scope.loaded` when you know
that everything was loaded. You can access element and scope in directive's **link** function. So you can do `$document.scrollTo(element, 70);` inside.

```
angular.module('app').directive('scrollTo', function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('loaded', function() {
        $document.scrollTo(element, 70);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Also you can use `resolve` property in your route to wait until everything is loaded before you render this page. In this case you can be sure that you scroll to right position

Comment: Thanks @Dimitriy. Actually that concept with directive was one of my many "tries". It worked somehow I expected, but beside all async data from firebase - we are loading some images - eg. Speakers photos, so even I manaded to catch moment after all data was loaded - images eventually also was messing witch my scroll position. Maybe we should sed some fixed heights to images - then after all data is loaded - css already "grab" area for heights and scroll will be ok also after images loaded after all? You think itss good solution?  We can try with resolve, but then situation the same - images.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/bimal1331/angular-images-loaded or http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

Comment: Thanks man! That's it - i have combined both of this. So first I'm watching scope variable 'loaded', and inside watch - I'm using that jquery plugin imagesloaded.desandro.com. So after all data is loaded I am waiting for all images to full load and then fire scroll. That plugin was exactly what I was looking for.